# Unabe to get token from DRF get-token api

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

**my custom signup api**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import serializers

class SignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    def validate_email(self, val):
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=val)
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email-ID already Exist")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return val

class SignupView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = SignupSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.data

        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')

        u = User(email=email, username=email)
        u.set_password(password)
        u.save()

        data = {
            'message': 'Successfully Created!',
            'data': {'id': u.id, 'email': email},
        }
        return Response(data)
```

**Toekn get api**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

when I hit `signup` api, it returns the success response, I mean

> {
>       'message': 'Successfully Created!',
>       'data': {'id': 1, 'email': 'xyz@gmail.com'} }

but when I try to generate/get token for this user using above token api, it says ..invalid credentials?

```
{
  "non_field_errors": [
    "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
  ]
}
```

however if I create a user using management command createsuperuser and use same api to get token it works?

is there someting wrong in signup api?

Comment: Are you assigning a Token to the user  _Token.objects.create(user=...)_ ? Can you check if your user has an associated Token in the database or not? If not, then you must, if you want to use TokenAuthentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `write_only=True` from your serializer. that would fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Error message actually tells you that your request is not able to reach the view, this happens because one of the middlewares raises an error.

The easiest (but pbly not very secure) solution would be to return the API token on successful signup, or to add another View with a login (which returns an token).

For a definite answer you would need to provide more information like the configuration for your Authentication Backends.

You can find here more Informations about Authentication in DRF
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined